# Facebook Targeting Search empty city list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

There's no city return from search targeting cites.

[image: Empty data]

Comment: Works fine [in Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DA%26type%3Dadgeolocation%26location_types%3D['city']&version=v3.1) - probably in issue with how exactly your parameters get encoded using your method of making the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location_types` is basically a string that contain a valid Json Array, so try this:

```
'location_types': '["city"]'
```

instead of:

```
'location_types': ['city']
```

Hope this help